# Changing attribute value on heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

In my rails app I have an attribute 'title' and I want to change all instance in the database where 'title' is, for example, 'apple pie' to 'apple cake'.  Is there a way to do this other than going through and changing each one individually as I have so many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a rake task to do the change:

```
namespace :update do

  desc "Update title"
  task :title_fix => :environment do
    MyClass.where(:title => 'old title').each do |t|
      t.update_attributes(title: 'new title')
    end
  end
end
```

And then at the command line run:

```
rake update:fix_title
```

Or, if you're brave, you can do it all in rails console like:

```
MyClass.where(:title => 'old title').each { |t| t.update_attributes(title: 'new title') }
```

But I HATE making database changes in a non-documented way...

Comment: ok, will try this (I'm not brave).  Will this update it in my heroku database though as opposed to just the localhost one?  And does the namespace rake go in routes.rb?

Comment: You'll add the rake file to your project (lib/tasks/update.rb) and then run it remotely with `heroku run rake update:fix_title`.  Be sure to try it out in a test environment first!  Never run such a thing on production without testing.

Comment: Ok, well it worked in my localhost (I had to rename as update.rake rather than update.rb).  I guess I need to bite the bullet and go for it with heroku.  What could go wrong :)?

Comment: actually when I try to run the rake on heroku it says Don't know how to build task 'update:fix_title'

Comment: heroku logs says

2013-02-27T02:52:28+00:00 heroku[run.7030]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake update:fix_title`
2013-02-27T02:52:28+00:00 heroku[run.7030]: State changed from starting to up
2013-02-27T02:52:38+00:00 heroku[run.7030]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-02-27T02:52:39+00:00 heroku[run.7030]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-27T02:52:39+00:00 heroku[run.7030]: State changed from up to complete

Comment: You checked in and pushed the rake file to heroku?

Comment: uumm.  I'm dumb.  sorry I hadn't pushed the changes  It worked - yay!